# How to unjar a jar when the directories are not present in the destination?

Tags: jar

There is a jar : my.jar that contains

```
folder1/First.txt
folder2/Second.txt
```

I need to unjar this into another location where folder1 and folder2 are not present. Is there a way to create directories in a go while running jar -xvf...? Or is there a better way to zip and unzip such files?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to extract both files in a single (base) directory or want to preserve the relative folder paths and extract it under folder1 and folder2? Do you want to do this programmatically or manually? Like on windows you can just rename the file with .zip extension and copy and paste the files with explorer.

Comment: I want to extract to different folders

Comment: jar -xvf my.jar should work then

Comment: No, that didn't work. `tar` worked fine

Comment: Works for me: D:\temp>jar -cvf folders.jar folder1/* folder2/*
added manifest
adding: folder1/Domino04may2012.pdf(in = 4511) (out= 2949)(deflated 34%)
adding: folder2/Dominos-21Dec2012.pdf(in = 4502) (out= 2908)(deflated 35%)

D:\temp>jar -xvf folders.jar
  created: META-INF/
 inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 inflated: folder1/Domino04may2012.pdf
 inflated: folder2/Dominos-21Dec2012.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for this...

Used : tar instead of jar

```
tar -cvf my.tar folder1/* folder2/*
tar -xvf my.tar
```